# How to create a scanner using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, antlr

Automated scanner construction refers to regular expressions being used to automatically create scanners, however, I am unsure on how this happens. I am reading 'Engineering a Compiler' to gain some understanding but i may have overlooked this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The **Engineering a Compiler** book, IIRC, glosses over construction of lexical scanners as being a topic well addressed by other books.

You want to get the Aho/Sethi/Ullman book **Compilers** (easily found anywhere), which I think has quite good treatment of how lexers are constructed from regular expressions.